# What do we call well-founded posets whose elements have a unique height?

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, terminology, order-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

What do we call those well-founded posets $P$ with the property that for every $x \in P$, all maximal chains in the lowerset generated by $x$ have the same length? Examples:

- The set of all finite subsets of a (possibly infinite) set.
- The set of all finite-dimensional vector subspaces of a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space.
- The set of all finite-dimensional affine subspaces a (possibly infinite-dimensional) affine space.
- Any set-theoretic [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28set_theory%29).
- Any poset that could reasonably be construed as an "abstract polytope."

Comment: A "locally graded poset" is given [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3148) as one so that each interval $[x,y]$ is graded, which is pretty close but perhaps not equivalent to what you want.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the right definition in another paper.  See my answer below.

Comment: "Bush, not George"? "Shrub"? "Quasi-tree"? "Well-founded poset where height is well-defined"? "Mountain"? "Gregor Clegane"? I'm starting to run out of ideas... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I like the first one. But I thought you did not like political jokes? For the record, I've been calling such posets "well-ranked."

Comment: Joking about silly former presidents is not political. Besides, well-ranked sounds reasonable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3107) paper gives the definition you want, if I understand you correctly:

> Definition 2.9. A poset $P$ will be called *locally ranked* if all its principal lower ideals are ranked.

Comment: Thanks, I think you might be right. Also, that paper looks relevant.