# First Order Logic and Euclidean Geometry System

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, first-order-logic

I'm studying for the first time the "First Order Logic". I encontered concepts as Axioms' System, theorems, inference rules,ecc..

Then i read [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) on wiki and i discovered that it's also composed of an axiom system and theorems.

So, in which way these 2 things are connected ? Can i use First Order Logic to describe Euclidean Geometry?

ps: The fact is that i'm also trying to understand the practical use of axioms' schemes and theorems in First Order Logic. What can i build with them...

Comment: Yes; see e.g. [Tarski's axiom system for geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms): "an axiom set for the substantial fragment of Euclidean geometry, called "elementary," that is formulable in first-order logic with identity, and requiring no set theory (due to Alfred Tarski 1959)."

Comment: See also the post [alternative-axioms-for-euclidean-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641549/are-there-any-alternative-axioms-for-euclidean-geometry) as well as [reference-request-for-set-theoretic-foundations-of-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586809/reference-request-for-set-theoretic-foundations-of-geometry).

Comment: Thanks Mauro im going to read these. Meanwhile, as a curiosity : it's true that the standard euclidean geometry not a first order logic, but it's possible to implement it in First Order Logic ?

Comment: Tarski's axiomatization **is** FOL.